# How can I require root privileges for invoking 'gpio' from WiringPi?

Tags: gpio, wiringpi, permissions

I removed my user from the `gpio` group, logged out and back in. I can still run e.g. `gpio write 25 1`.

I see from [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79603/105846) how the memory mapping and permissions changed between Jessie and Stretch, but the instructions for leaving the `gpio` group did not seem to work. I asked on IRC, and someone told me that WiringPi now uses "set uid" for the permission structure, and I see that mentioned on the WiringPi website [here](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/):

> The gpio command is designed to be installed as a setuid program and called by a normal user without using the sudo command or logging in as root.

Am I going to have to compile WiringPi from source in order to change this behaviour?

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.50
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi 3, Revision: 02, Memory: 1024MB, Maker: Unknown05 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wiring Pi - Root not required?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79600/wiring-pi-root-not-required)

Comment: @Dougie my question is not a duplicate of that question. The answer to that question doesn't even apply to my situation, because the gpio group doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing WiringPi from the official Raspbian repositories (on Stretch or later, I believe) will create an executable file at `/usr/bin/gpio`.

- By default, the owner of the file is root, i.e. `0`, and the group is root, i.e. `0`.
- By default, the permissions on the file is 4755. The interesting part of this is the `4`, which is the setuid bit. It enables executables to be run with the same privileges as the file's owner, in this case `0`, or root.

I fixed the problem simply by removing the setuid bit with `chmod 0755 $(which gpio)`. GPIO can now only be controlled by the root user, even if a user is a member of the `gpio` group. Considering that there are other groups like `i2c` and `spi`, I'm not sure if this completely mitigates security problems.

I wish the `gpio` group could enable/disable GPIO control for users.

Comment: Your question may be misleading as you mean the wiringPi gpio utility.  None of this affects other commands written using the wiringPi library.

Comment: @joan Sorry, I'm not sure what you're talking about. Can you explain more about why my question is misleading? I stated WiringPi in my question. Are you referring to the WiringPi C library, as opposed to the command line version?

Comment: Not sure how. Your solution is for a utility called gpio which uses the wiringPi library.

Comment: @joan The WiringPi package installs, among other things, the `gpio` utility. I have no idea what you're talking about, sorry. I'm just going to leave it at that.

Comment: *"I wish the gpio group could enable/disable GPIO control for users"* -> Set the executable `0770` and `chgrp gpio $(which gpio)`.